# Method declaration is different from general declaration

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, variadic-functions

When debugging i found this method.

```
   - (void)sendPublicEvent:(NSInteger)type, ... KNCONTANT_VALUE
```

The method declaration is different from  generation method declaration.

I do not understand why it postfix after type `,...` KNCONTANT_VALUE`
I want to know why method declaration is different,any one advice me!
@thanks in Advance

Comment: can you post that entire method?

Comment: Tag better, for better answers from peers, I just guessed, might be my answer is not fully correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method is taking a variable argument.

See this example:

In .h

```
-(void)variableArgument:(NSString *)string, ...;
```

In .m

```
- (void)variableArgument:(NSString *)string, ... {
  va_list args;
  va_start(args, string);
  NSLogv(string, args);
  va_end(args);
}
```

And `KNCONTANT_VALUE` is showing that this should be your last constant value after the Integer values.

When we deal with strings we use : `-(void)variableArgument:(NSString *)string, ... NS_REQUIRES_NIL_TERMINATION;`